# Match multiple lines with a regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following text:

```
--------------030805090908050805080502
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part16.07030906.00090703@highcontrast.ro>

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kAAQAEAAAARgAA/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAA
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kAAQAEAAAARgAA/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAA
QBQH/9k=
--------------030805090908050805080502
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-ID: <part17.07010805.02020809@highcontrast.ro>

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kAAQAEAAAARgAA/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAA
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAgAAZABkAAD/7AARRHVja3kAAQAEAAAARgAA/+4ADkFkb2JlAGTAAAAA
juu41lRHFLufPCAID//Z
--------------030805090908050805080502--
```

And I need to get with Regex in C# 2 parts:

1. between the first and the second occurence of the string `"--------------030805090908050805080502"`
2. between the strings `"--------------030805090908050805080502"` and `"--------------030805090908050805080502--"`

I tried this regex:

```
--------------030805090908050805080502(\r.*)*--------------030805090908050805080502
```

but in C# `regex.Matches(...)` returns only `"--------------030805090908050805080502"`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches( text, @"([-]+\d{24})
                                                 (?<Content>.*?)
                                                 (?=\1)", 
                                         RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace | 
                                         RegexOptions.Singleline );

foreach ( Match match in matches )
{
    Console.WriteLine( 
        string.Format( "match: {0}\n\n", 
                       match.Groups[ "Content" ].Value ) );
}
```

**Update:** This expression will find all matches that come between two occurrences of a number.  If the number needs to be a specific one, rather than any 24-digit number, change "\d{24}" to the number you want to match.

Comment: How your Regex will look like if I don't know the iteration number for "--------------030805090908050805080502" ?

Comment: Replace the iteration number with \d+ to match any string of digits.  If the iteration number is always 24 digits, \d{24} will do it.

Comment: I wanted to say that I don't know the number of lines in which "--------------030805090908050805080502" appear.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tabh47cf.aspx):

```
var str = stringToParse.Split(
    new[] { "--------------030805090908050805080502" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.None);
Console.WriteLine(str[1]);
```

Comment: At this time this operation is done with split, but I want to use Regex.